# Regex: how to match "sda" but not "sdaa"?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I'm filtering `lsblk -r` output to list drives that are *not* sda. I wont to list drives that are sdab, sdac etc however.

What I had perviously was:

```
lsblk -r | grep -o '^[a-z]*' | grep -v sda | grep -v sr | sort | uniq
```

That returned a list of drives that are not sda and not sr, but it fails when the drive names go beyond sdz, becasue the grep matches sdaa for sda and purges that.

I tried including a white space in my grep pattern to no avail.

Example (fake) lsblk -r output that I use for testing:

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda 8:0 0 2,7T 0 disk 
sda1 8:1 0 14,9G 0 part [SWAP]
sda2 8:2 0 93,1G 0 part /
sda3 8:3 0 984,6G 0 part /data
sda4 8:4 0 725,4G 0 part /media/backup
sda5 8:5 0 16M 0 part 
sda6 8:6 0 498G 0 part /home
sda7 8:7 0 478,5G 0 part 
sdc 8:32 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdd 8:48 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sde 8:64 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdf 8:80 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdg 8:96 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdh 8:112 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdi 8:128 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdj 8:144 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdl 8:176 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdab 8:144 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdac 8:176 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdad 8:144 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdaz 8:176 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdab1 8:144 1 7,5G 0 part 
sdac1 8:176 1 7,5G 0 part 
sdad1 8:144 1 7,5G 0 part 
sdaz1 8:176 1 7,5G 0 part
```

Comment: Can you please add also the expected reesult from your example

Comment: `sed` for removing only `"sda "` (without quotes), `sed -n '/sda[^ ]/p'`

Answer (score 1):

Use a word boundary:

```
grep -v 'sda\b'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can perform plain string comparisons and avoid multiple `grep` commands as well:

```
lsblk -r | awk '$1 != "sda" && $1 != "sr" { print $1 }' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Use negative look-ahead in a PCRE regex:

```
grep -P '^sda(?!a)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just anchor your matches to search for exact strings:

```
... | grep -v '^sda$' | grep -v '^sr$' | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the whole thing in Perl instead:

```
lsblk -r | perl -lne '($d) = /^([a-z]*)/; $h{$d}++ unless $d =~ /^(sda|dr)$/; END { print for sort keys %h }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of `sda` right?

```
sed -n '/sda[^ ]/p'
```

For ignoring both `sda` and `sr`,

```
sed -n '/\(sda[^ ]\|sr\)/p'
```

Output for the given input,

```
sda1 8:1 0 14,9G 0 part [SWAP]
sda2 8:2 0 93,1G 0 part /
sda3 8:3 0 984,6G 0 part /data
sda4 8:4 0 725,4G 0 part /media/backup
sda5 8:5 0 16M 0 part 
sda6 8:6 0 498G 0 part /home
sda7 8:7 0 478,5G 0 part 
sdab 8:144 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdac 8:176 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdad 8:144 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdaz 8:176 1 7,5G 0 disk 
sdab1 8:144 1 7,5G 0 part 
sdac1 8:176 1 7,5G 0 part 
sdad1 8:144 1 7,5G 0 part 
sdaz1 8:176 1 7,5G 0 part
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lsblk -r | grep disk | grep -v 'sda ' | grep -v sr | cut -d' ' -f1
```

It'll filter only disk entries from lsblk -r output, then rule out 'sda ', and then 'sr'. No need for `sort | uniq` if you do the `grep disk` first.

Example output for your example input:

```
sdc
sdd
sde
sdf
sdg
sdh
sdi
sdj
sdl
sdab
sdac
sdad
sdaz
```

Comment: `lsblk -r | awk '/disk/ && $1 != "sda" && $1 != "sr" { print $1 }'` will be fast since there is only one command `awk`